# CRUD operations with arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to create a pet app that allows user input to enter a pet name, update the pet name and delete the pet name. Here is what I have so far. I have made an array for the create method but I can't figure out how to use it in the update or delete methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Menu2 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        showMainMenu();
    }

    public static void showMainMenu(){
        System.out.println("--- MAIN MENU ---");
        System.out.println("1. Create Pet");
        System.out.println("2. Update Pet");
        System.out.println("3. Delete Pet");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter your Choice : ");

        int option = scan.nextInt();

        switch(option){
            case 1:
                createPet();
                break;
            case 2:
                updatePet();
                break;
            case 3:
                deletePet();
                break;
            case 4: 
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option!");
                showMainMenu();
        }
     
    }
    public static void createPet(){
       
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String newPet = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Pet Name: ");
        String newPet = myObj.nextLine();
        String newPetArray[] = newPet.split(" ");
       // newPet = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Pet Name is " + newPet);

        // use for READ
        for (int i = 0; i < newPetArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(newPetArray[i]);
        }
        showMainMenu();
    }
    public static void updatePet() {

    }

    public static void deletePet() {

    }
}
```

Comment: When enterting pet name inside createPet, what is the expected input format ?

Comment: I would like to create a new pet name and store it so I am able to display it, update it, and delete it.

Comment: is it compulsory that you need to use array, why not arraylist ?

Comment: I looked into arraylists but I couldn't figure out how to implement it into the createPet method.

Comment: what is the expected behavior of pet update method ? do you want to update the name ?

Comment: @wyattearp1218 Your class has no field for storing the array you create in `createPet()`. For this to work you have to save at least the created array somewhere where *all* methods can access it. Currently the array in `newPetArray` (if that is supposed to be the storage of all pets) exists only inside the `createPet()` method and is gone as soon as the method ends.

Comment: @wyattearp1218 You are calling the `showMainMenu()` method from inside the `createPet()` method to go "back" to the main menu. This also means that this `createPet()` doesn't finish. You don't do it like that. Do **not** call `showMainMenu()` from your `createPet()` method and instead add a `while` loop in your `showMainMenu()` which keeps the user in the main menu until the user quits the program (like when the user enters `0` and you have added such a check in your code).

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to store the pets in an array, for updating you would loop through the array (such as with a "for" or "while" loop), identify the index of the entry to be updated and update it.  This could also be done with filters, but that would be a more advanced approach.

In order to delete the pet, you would need to find the pet (like you would in the update portion) and then shift all the remaining pets forward, so newPetArray[x] gets the value of newPetArray[x+1] and the last pet gets removed.

This task is easier with other datastructures, like ArrayList's, that support removing and inserting items directly.

Comment: I tried creating an ArrayList in the createPet method. I this possible? I couldn't get it to work. I was importing the ArrayList package.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to implement the scanner into the ArrayList. I understand it when you are manually adding items to it.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned the details about the update function, I am assuming it is going to update the name of the pet present in the list. As ArrayList is more flexible when it comes to array in terms of addition of deletion and since you havent specified that you need to use array in particular, I'm providing the solution with ArrayList.

> Logic for Updation

You iterate through the list and when the element matches, you simply update the name

> Logic for Deletion

You iterate through the list and when the element matches, you simply remove the element present at that index.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu2 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<String> petList;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        showMainMenu();
        scan.close();
    }

    public static void showMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("--- MAIN MENU ---");
        System.out.println("1. Create Pet");
        System.out.println("2. Update Pet");
        System.out.println("3. Delete Pet");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter your Choice : ");

        int option = scan.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                createPet();
                break;
            case 2:
                updatePet();
                break;
            case 3:
                deletePet();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option!");
                showMainMenu();
        }

    }

    public static void createPet() {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Pet Name: ");
        String newPet = myObj.nextLine();

        String newPetArray[] = newPet.split(" ");
        petList = new ArrayList<>();

        // use for READ
        for (int i = 0; i < newPetArray.length; i++) {
            petList.add(newPetArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("pets in list are " + petList);
        showMainMenu();
    }

    public static void updatePet() {

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the pet to be updated");
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the updated name");
        String newName = scan.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < petList.size(); i++) {
            if (petList.get(i).equals(name)) {
                petList.set(i, newName);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("pets in list after updating the pet  " + petList);
        showMainMenu();
    }

    public static void deletePet() {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the pet to be deleted");
        String name = scan.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < petList.size(); i++) {
            if (petList.get(i).equals(name)) {
                petList.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("pets in list after deleting the specific pet " + petList);
        showMainMenu();
    }
}
```

and the output is as follows:

```
--- MAIN MENU ---
1. Create Pet
2. Update Pet
3. Delete Pet
4. Exit
Enter your Choice : 1
Enter Pet Name: buddy max mac 
pets in list are [buddy, max, mac]
--- MAIN MENU ---
1. Create Pet
2. Update Pet
3. Delete Pet
4. Exit
Enter your Choice : 2
Enter the name of the pet to be updated
mac
Enter the updated name
macKing
pets in list after updating the pet  [buddy, max, macKing]
--- MAIN MENU ---
1. Create Pet
2. Update Pet
3. Delete Pet
4. Exit
Enter your Choice : 3
Enter the name of the pet to be deleted
max
pets in list after deleting the specific pet [buddy, macKing]
--- MAIN MENU ---
1. Create Pet
2. Update Pet
3. Delete Pet
4. Exit
Enter your Choice : 4
```